# Having a POJO like feature in KarateAPI?

Tags: rest-assured, karate, web-api-testing

I have been using Karate and RestAssured for sometime. There are advantages and downside of both tools of course. Right now I have a RestAssured project where I have Request and Response object and POJOs. My requests wraps my endpoint and send my POJOs to those endpoint. I do all my Headers, etc configuration in an abstract layer. In case I need to override them, I override them during the test. If not, Its a two lines of code for me to trigger an endpoint.

My way of working with happy path and negative path of an edpoint is that I initialize the POJO before every test with new values in the constructor. Then I override the value that I want in test scope. For example, if I want to test a negative case for password field, I set this field to empty string during the test. But other fields are already set to some random stuff before the test.

But I dont know how to achieve this with Karate.

Karate allows me to create a JSON representation of my request body and define my parameters as seen below example.

```
    {
  "firstName": "<name>",
  "lastName": "<lastName>",
  "email": "<email>",
  "role": <role>
  }
```

Then in every test I have to fill all the fields with some data.

```
 |token    |value|
  |name     |'canberk'|
  |lastName |''|
  |email    |'canberk@blbabla.com'|
  |role     |'1'|
```

and

```
|token    |value|
      |name     |''|
      |lastName |'akduygu'|
      |email    |'canberk@blbabla.com'|
      |role     |'1'|
```

It goes on like this.

It's ok with a 4 fields JSON body but when the body starts to have more than 20 fields, it become a pain to initialise every field for every test.

Does Karate have a way of achieving this problem with a predefined steps of I need to come up with a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are advantages and downside of both tools of course.

I'm definitely biased, but IMHO the only disadvantage of Karate compared to REST-assured is that you don't get compile time safety :) I hope that you have seen [this comparison](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ETTrdMVcBXaPjdKY-_67zCWBsi2Ctc5DIQUIfr02H7A/edit).

Karate has multiple ways to do what you want. Here's what I would do.

1. create a JSON file that has all your "happy path" values set
2. use the `read()` syntax to load the file (which means this is re-usable across multiple tests)
3. use the `set` keyword to update only the field for your scenario or negative test

You can get even more fancier if you use [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions).

1. create a JSON file that has all your "happy path" values set and the values you want to vary look like `foo: '##(foo)'`
2. before using `read()` you init some variables for e.g. `* def foo = 'bar'` and if you use `null` that JSON key will even be removed from the JSON
3. `read()` the JSON. it is ready for use !

You can refer to this file that demonstrates some of these concepts for XML, and you may get more ideas: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

Comment: How the hell did I miss the 'set' keyword!!!
That's exactly what I want :)

Comment: Another simple question, is it possible to use my custom javascript method calls in the Example section of a Scenario Outline? Or all those value has to be static?

Comment: @CanberkAkduygu you can figure out creative ways to mix `Examples` and dynamic JavaScript: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/examples.feature

Comment: I am working on that example, but calling my custom javascript method is not working in data table. May be I am doing something wrong. I need to create a different email address for each execution. So I have a javascript method to create a random number. I need to add this value to my email data set. Thanks once again for quick replies

Comment: @CanberkAkduygu then look at the `table` keyword. it works a little differently. but I think all you need to do is move the JS method out of the examples-table, above it as part of the steps. and that will maybe `set` the e-mail. should work.