# passing variable to json file while matching response in karate

Tags: json, karate

I'm validating my response from a GET call through a .json file

match response == read('match_response.json')

Now I want to reuse this file for various other features as only one field in the .json varies. Let's say this param in the json file is "varyingField"

I'm trying to pass this field every time I am matching the response but not able to

- def varyingField = 'VARIATION1'

match response == read('match_response.json') {'varyingField' : '#(varyingField)'}}

In the json file I have 
"varyingField": "#(varyingField)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use an argument to `read` for a JSON file ? Sorry such a thing is not supported in Karate, please read the docs.

Use this pattern:

1. create a JSON file that has all your "happy path" values set
2. use the read() syntax to load the file (which means this is re-usable across multiple tests)
3. use the set keyword to update only the field for your scenario or negative test

For more details, refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51896522/143475