# What should be contains in Karate framework Scenario (less perfomance)

Tags: karate

I got a test case, I should create an order and get some response and match it with my layout then I must update my order and get the current response for matching it with my second layout, and then I update one more time and should take one more update response. I realized id like:
I create a file that contains layouts, and I call it from my scenario, this is ok because I call it one time, also I got file with scenarios:

@getresponse
Scenario: Get response

```
* url 'link'
And header heafer
Then method GET
#Logs
* print karate.prevRequest
* print response
#---
* def messages = karate.jsonPath(response, "$..message")
* def log = getlog(messages)
* def allDRXML = log.substring(xmlBeginning, xmlEnd)
* xml LogThatIMustHave= allDRXML


Every time I should call @getresponse.LogThatIMustHave from my test file like a method in Java, but when calling it thirdntime system spend about 10 minutes or more to get it. When I call it from test file every variable is different! Can I paste all actions above in one scenario, or I must for every update create a new scenarios and made scenarios for every action?
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question at all. you seem to be doing so many un-necessary things. I suggest saving different files with each "layout" and also read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60434757/143475

Comment: I need to create order check response, then I need to update order and check response and then one more time update and check. If I create one Scenario and made all this flow, I need to call the scenario that should get the necessary fields from the response three times during flow but when I do it, the system spends about 15 minutes for the test (especially for the last call), but if I made two of them in one scenario and proceed in the second one, time that system spent about 1-2 minutes. I need to do it in one scenario.

Comment: Why performance is getting worse when I call few times one scenario from another file? And how can I fix it?

Comment: my only suggestion is that you follow this process, or you can wait for someone else who knows better: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue