# How do you parameterize the read function in karate

Tags: karate

How do you parameterize the read function in karate?
For example:

```
* def testcases = read("../TestCases/TestCases.csv")
* def wflowjson = '<wflowjson>'-- wflowjson is coming from TestCases.csv
* def expectedResponse = read(wflowjson)
* print 'expectedResponse--->' expectedResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as parameterizing a `read` of a JSON or CSV file.

But when variables are defined, they can get substituted within the file using embedded expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60434757/143475

Note that you can use variables for the file-name when you `read` for example:

```
* def myJson = read(someVar + '/foo.json')
```