# Karate: Adding value for keys in request other than string dynamically

Tags: karate

I have a following request for my api. i have externalised it so that i could create dynamic requests.

**Request file:**

```
{
  "barcodeIds": [
    0
  ],
  "batchSize": 1,
  "email": "",
  "etixTicketNumber": "#ETICKET#",
  "fileKey": "#FILEKEY#",
  "flightNr": "",
  "guids": "#GUID#",
  "lhid": "",
  "loadBarcodes": true,
  "loadCompleteTrip": true,
  "mapsFunctionName": "MBPQUERY",
  "offset": 0,
  "originAirportCode": "",
  "passengerForename": "#FIRSTNAME#",
  "passengerLastname": "#LASTNAME#",
  "serialNumbers": "#SERIALNUMBER#",
  "telNumber": ""
}
```

**Feature file:**

```
* def guid = []
* def attr = [{regex: '#GUID#', value : '#(guid)'}]
```

But the request i want to create here should include empty array for serial number and guid.
However, when i try to add the parameter values in the script the request generates the following:

```
"guid" : "[]", "serialNumber" : "[]"
```

But the expected is:

```
"guid" : [], "serialNumber" : []
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a better data-driven approach. For example:

```
* def baz = []
* def foo = { bar: '#(baz)'}
* match foo == { bar: [] }
```

Take some time to go through the docs and other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51896522/143475

Comment: Oops, This is same as what i already tried and the output looks like what is mentioned in the question itself. The request is kept in an external file. And when we try to assign the parameter value in the feature file, it automatically takes " ", because of the following parameter defined in quotes in the external file.

Comment: added the feature file code as well for clear understanding.

Comment: @user1873274 sorry I'm going to pass on this one. follow this process if you can: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue