# Is there any way to use Rest Assured together with Karate?

Tags: java, api, rest, karate

I want to use Rest Assured inner functions with Karate tests parallel execution.
Is this possible to use these frameworks together?

Comment: as the author of karate I have to ask, why on earth would you want to use the rest-assured "inner functions" whatever that is. I recommend you take a closer look at karate and do some research: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51896522/143475

Comment: I’m currently using Rest Assured at my project, it will be hard to switch one to another, so I just want to keep my project’s structure, but with adding Karate’s parallel execution. Anyway, the way how parallel execution works at your framework, brings me a lot of motivation to learn it much closer

Comment: my understanding is that you cannot because RA does NOT support parallel-execution: https://groups.google.com/g/rest-assured/c/NEhrDwIYQag/m/c6KYLTiSBgAJ?pli=1

Comment: Okey, thank you for your reply. I most repeat, that your framework’s structure and parallel execution makes me have a lot of motivation to learn it much closer